# Angular JS indefinite execution of a function called inside a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an app using google's QPX express and I created a service to call the QPX web service.

I noticed that when I inspect certain functions, I see that they are executing indefinitely. The functions are $scope.pageArray, $scope.humanizeTime.Can someone help me identify why this is the case.

I have an understanding of why this is happening, but am not able to identify the root cause. Somehow/Somewhere in the code I am suggesting to Angular that the model has changed and therefore Angular is running a $scope.$digest, but I cant seem to identify where.

```
 var resultController =planeSearchControllers.controller('resultController',['$scope','$http','commonSharedService','flight', function($scope,$http,commonSharedService,flight){
        var isDebugEnabled = true;
        $scope.showResults = false;
        $scope.showPlaneSearch = true;
        $scope.showPlaneError = false;
        $scope.planeView = false;
        $scope.historyView = false;
        $scope.$watch(function() {return commonSharedService.getMode();},function(newValue,oldValue){
            console.log('New Mode is' + newValue);
            if(newValue == 'plane'){
                $scope.planeView = true;
                $scope.historyView = false;
                $scope.historyObj = [];
            }else if(newValue == 'history'){
                getHistory(commonSharedService.getUserName());
                $scope.planeView = false;
                $scope.historyView = true;
            }
        });
        $scope.$watch(function (){return commonSharedService.getValidateInputs();},function (newValue,oldValue){
            if(isDebugEnabled){
                console.log('Value is changed for getValidateInputs ' + 'New Value is -->'+ newValue);
            }
            $scope.validateInputs = newValue;
            if($scope.validateInputs == true)  {
                makePlaneCall();
                $scope.showResults = true;
                commonSharedService.setValidateInputs(undefined);
                $scope.errorMsg = commonSharedService.getErrorMsg();
            }
            if($scope.validateInputs == false)  {
                $scope.showResults = false;
                commonSharedService.setValidateInputs(undefined);
                $scope.errorMsg = commonSharedService.getErrorMsg();
            }
        });
        $scope.humanizeTime = function(time){
            //var duration = new moment.duration(time, "minutes");
            //var hours = duration.hours();
            //var minutes = duration.minutes();
            var hours = Math.floor(time/60);
            var minutes = time - (60 * hours);
            var str = hours == 0 ? '': hours + 'hours ' ;
            str += minutes == 0 ? '': minutes + 'minutes';
            return str;
        };
        //Page Filtering
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.numPerPage = 5;
        $scope.maxSize = 5;
        $scope.numPerPage = 5;
        $scope.numPages = function () {
            if($scope.tripOption!=null )
                return Math.ceil($scope.tripOption.length / $scope.numPerPage);
            else
                return 0;
        };
        $scope.pageArray = function () {
            var input = [];
            for(var i=0;i<$scope.numPages();i++){
                input[i] = i+1;
            }
            return input;
        };
        var paging = function(arrayIn,pageNo,perPageNo){
            var outArray = [];
            if(arrayIn!=undefined){
                var from = perPageNo * (pageNo-1);
                var to = from + perPageNo;
                if (to > arrayIn.length)
                    to= arrayIn.length;
                //console.log(from);
                //console.log(to);
                //console.log(outArray);
                for (var i =from; i<to ;i++)
                    outArray.push(arrayIn[i]);
            }
            return outArray;
        };

        $scope.paginationFilter = function (){
            return paging($scope.tripOption,$scope.currentPage,$scope.numPerPage);
        };

        var makePlaneCall = function () {
            $scope.appendObj = commonSharedService.getAppendObj();
            $scope.jsonObj  = commonSharedService.getJsonObj();
            $scope.jsonObj['time'] =  moment().format("ddd Do,YYYY HH:mm a");
            var user = commonSharedService.getUserName();
            if(user != undefined)
                setHistory(user,$scope.jsonObj);
            $scope.planeRequest = {};
            $scope.requestObj = {};
            var slice = [];
            var slice1 ={};
            var slice2 ={};
            var slice3 ={};
                {
                    slice1['origin'] = $scope.appendObj['departAirport'];
                    slice1['destination']= $scope.appendObj['multiCity'] ? $scope.appendObj['interimAirport'] :$scope.appendObj['arrivalAirport'];
                    slice1['date']= $scope.appendObj['departureDate'];
                    slice1['permittedDepartureTime'] ={
                        "earliestTime": $scope.appendObj['departureEarliest']
                    };
                    if($scope.appendObj['preferredCabin']!=undefined){
                        slice1['preferredCabin'] = $scope.appendObj['preferredCabin'];
                    }
                    slice.push(slice1);
                }
                if($scope.appendObj['multiCity'] == true){
                    slice2['origin'] = $scope.appendObj['interimAirport'];
                    slice2['destination']= $scope.appendObj['arrivalAirport'];
                    slice2['date']= $scope.appendObj['interimDate'];
                    slice2['permittedDepartureTime'] ={
                        "earliestTime": $scope.appendObj['interimEarliest']
                    };
                    if($scope.appendObj['preferredCabin']!=undefined){
                        slice2['preferredCabin'] = $scope.appendObj['preferredCabin'];
                    }
                    slice.push(slice2);
                }
                if($scope.appendObj['isReturnFlight'] == 'true'){
                    slice3['origin']=$scope.appendObj['arrivalAirport'];
                    slice3['destination'] = $scope.appendObj['departAirport'];
                    slice3['date']=$scope.appendObj['arrivalDate'];
                    slice3['permittedDepartureTime'] ={
                        "earliestTime": $scope.appendObj['arrivalEarliest']
                    };
                    if($scope.appendObj['preferredCabin']!=undefined){
                        slice3['preferredCabin'] = $scope.appendObj['preferredCabin'];
                    }
                    slice.push(slice3);
                }
                for(var property in $scope.jsonObj){
                    if($scope.jsonObj.hasOwnProperty(property)){
                        $scope.requestObj[property] = $scope.jsonObj[property];
                    }
                }
            $scope.requestObj['slice'] = slice;
            //$scope.requestObj['passengers'] = $scope.jsonObj['passengers'];
            $scope.requestObj['solutions'] = 5;
            $scope.requestObj['refundable'] = false;
            $scope.planeRequest['request'] =$scope.requestObj;
            flight.search($scope.planeRequest,function(response){
                $scope.result= response;
                $scope.info = $scope.result.trips.data;
                $scope.tripOption = $scope.result.trips.tripOption;
                //console.log($scope.tripOption);
                if($scope.tripOption!=null){
                     {
                        $scope.airport = $scope.info.airport;
                        $scope.city = $scope.info.city;
                        $scope.aircraft = $scope.info.aircraft;
                        $scope.tax = $scope.info.tax;
                        $scope.carrier = $scope.info.carrier;
                        $scope.showPlaneError = false;
                        $scope.paginationFilter();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    $scope.showPlaneError = true;
                    $scope.planeSearchErrorMsg = "No Solutions found. Please check your airport codes and set more liberal parameter for the search to see if something turns up.";
                }

                console.log(response);
            },function(response){
                console.log("error");
                $scope.result= response;
                console.log(response);
            });
        };

        function setHistory(userName,historyObj){
            var firstTime=true;
            var ref = new Firebase("http://flight-searchdb.firebaseIO.com/History");
            var historyRef = ref.child(userName);
            historyRef.on("value", function(historySnapshotObj) {
                if(firstTime==true){
                    var historySnapshot = historySnapshotObj.val();
                    console.log(historySnapshot);
                    var count;
                    if(historySnapshot!=null)
                        count = historySnapshot['count'];
                    console.log(count);
                    var obj ={};
                    if(count == undefined) {
                        obj['count'] = 0;
                        obj[0]= historyObj;
                    }else if(count < 9){
                        obj['count'] = ++count;
                        obj[count]= historyObj;
                    }else if(count == 9){
                        console.log(3);
                        obj['count'] = count;
                        for(var i=0;i<9;i++)
                            obj[i+1] = historySnapshot[i];
                        obj[0] = historyObj;
                    }
                    firstTime = false;
                    historyRef.update(obj);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Wrong Place");
                }
            }, function (errorObject) {
                console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
            });
        }
        function getHistory(userName){
            var ref = new Firebase("http://flight-searchdb.firebaseIO.com/History");
            var usersRef = ref.child(userName);
            usersRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
                for (var i=0;i<10;i++){}
                var userHistory = snapshot.val();
                var count;
                var array=[];
                if(userHistory!=null)
                    count = userHistory['count'];
                if (count!=undefined) {
                    for (var i=0;i <count ; i++)
                        array.push(userHistory[i]);
                }
                $scope.historyObj = array;
                $scope.$digest();
            }, function (errorObject) {
                console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
            });
        }

    }]);
```

I tested all functions and all of them seem to be working , except that when I added the pagination I dont see any result.

P.S : I was using a filter before , but for the sake of debug , I moved the pagination logic into the controller. I also understand that I could have used a directive.(since I am displaying the result at only place, I decided to skip it.)

I am also adding the view below , in which I am using the controller.

```
   <!-- Result Body-->
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-7" data-ng-controller="resultController">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div data-ng-show="planeView">
                            <div data-ng-hide="showResults">
                                <div><span></span><span>{{errorMsg}}</span></div>
                            </div>
                            <div data-ng-show="showResults">
                                <div class="showPlaneSearch" data-ng-show="showPlaneSearch">
                                    <div class="query thumbnail">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                                                <span >Page</span>
                                                <select data-ng-model="currentPage" id="selectPage" class="form-control col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5"
                                                        data-ng-options="value for value in pageArray()" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="right"
                                                        data-content="Select Page Number">
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <ul class="planesResult">
                                        {{currentPage}}
                                        {{numPerPage}}
                                        <li ng-repeat="trip in paginationFilter" class="thumbnail">
                                            <div class="row phoneContents">
                                                <!-- Image -->
                                                <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md col-lg-2">
                                                    <a href="#/phones/{{phone.id}}" class="thumb"><img src="images/Airplane-Icon.png" /></a>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- Trip Total $$$ -->
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10" >
                                                    <span class="price">{{trip.saleTotal}}</span>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- Everything except Image -->
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10">
                                                    <!--Each  Slice -->
                                                    <div ng-repeat="slice in trip.slice" class="slice row">
                                                        <!-- Each Segment Origin-->
                                                <span class="col-xs-hidden col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                                    <span  ng-repeat="segment in slice.segment">
                                                            <span > {{segment.leg[0].origin}}--></span>
                                                            <span ng-show="$last"> {{segment.leg[0].destination}} </span>
                                                    </span>
                                                </span>
                                                        <!-- Each Segment Origin-->
                                                        <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">{{humanizeTime(slice.duration)}}</span>
                                                <span  ng-repeat="segment in slice.segment" class="col-xs-hidden col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                                                    <span ng-show="$first"> Depart at  {{}} </span>
                                                </span>
                                                        <br>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="showPlaneError" data-ng-show="showPlaneError">
                                    <span class="thumbnail">{{planeSearchErrorMsg}}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div data-ng-show="historyView">
                            <pre>{{historyObj | json}}</pre>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: plunker will be useful

Comment: paginationFilter and tripOption. i see these are circular - one inside another. and another inside one.

Comment: @cyan  I thought of a plunker , but I designed it so poorly(not modular enough) that It was difficult for me to do that. can you please post the lines that are circular.

Comment: what is wrong in that angular is calling digest?

Comment: no the $scope.pageArray, $scope.humanizeTime functions keep on executing indefinetely. It is like calling these functions multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I can't run code, but i see something suspicious, worth changing:

two places:

```
 $scope.paginationFilter = function (){
        return paging($scope.tripOption,
```

and

```
       if($scope.tripOption!=null){
                 {
                    $scope.airport = $scope.info.airport;
                    $scope.city = $scope.info.city;
                    $scope.aircraft = $scope.info.aircraft;
                    $scope.tax = $scope.info.tax;
                    $scope.carrier = $scope.info.carrier;
                    $scope.showPlaneError = false;
                    $scope.paginationFilter();
```

I see that when `tripOption!= null` you call `paginationFilter` function, which uses tripOption.

Comment: I have removed that reference as well. But still the problem persists.